# Upload a file using json API android

Tags: java, android, json, file-upload, curl

Hi im working on a android app for bayfiles, where you can view, delete and upload files. They have a API for uploading files to their server using their Json API, but i can figure out how to do so. What the documentation says:

> /file/uploadUrl
>
> { error: "", uploadUrl: , progressUrl:  }
>
> The returned URL is valid for a limited amount of time, you need to
>   request a new one for each upload. Issue a POST request to the
>   "uploadUrl" to upload the file. You can poll "progressUrl" to fetch
>   the current progress. The POST request needs to be multipart/form-data
>   encoded and contain a "file" field. cUrl example: curl -F
>   "file=@somefile.rar"
>   "http://s6.baycdn.com/upload/93b37e57/4e691e0c/6/0?X-Progress-ID=4e639fcd34CC2F73796CF81679C605643A8F99CF"
>   Note: in order to upload a file to your account, you need to first log
>   in using /account/login and then append ?session=XYZ to
>   /file/uploadUrl On success, the "uploadUrl" will respond with an
>   object: { error: "", fileId: , size: , sha1: ,
>   infoToken: , deleteToken: , linksUrl: ,
>   downloadUrl: , deleteUrl: , }

I cant understand how to do this using android. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code to upload your file

```
private void uploadVideo(String yourfilepath) throws ParseException, IOException {

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                //post request to send the video 
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("your link to uploadd");
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy( policy);
                FileBody video_file1 = new FileBody(new File(videoPath));
                MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
                reqEntity.addPart("your argument that your server take", video_file1);                    
                httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

                // DEBUG
                System.out.println( "executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine( ) );
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httppost );
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity( );

                // DEBUG
                System.out.println( response.getStatusLine( ) );
                if (resEntity != null) {
                  System.out.println( EntityUtils.toString( resEntity ) );
                } // end if
                if (resEntity != null) {
                  resEntity.consumeContent( );
                } // end if

                httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( );
            }
```